# Command 'Dev Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Container' resulted in error

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a docker container. I get the following error:

> Command 'Dev Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Container' resulted in error
> command 'remote-containers.rebuildAndReopenInContainer' not found.

I am using Code-OSS on Manjaro. Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc820.

Comment: Remote-Containers might not installed or enabled in your vscode. ```Ctrl+Shift+X``` and search for "Remote - Containers". If it's not installed, install it and reload vscode.

Comment: which extension do you mean? Dev Containers is installed

Comment: Check the Installation of Remote - Containers Extension; In vscode, go to the Extensions view search for **Remote - Containers**, and check if it's installed. If not, install it. If it's already installed, try disabling and re-enabling it.

Comment: I installed Dev containers, which is Remote - Containers. If I search for Remote - Containers the only thing I find is dev containers.